# Replace $& regex group

Tags: regex, jsrender, regex-group

Boris Moore's great jsrender library [has one bug](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender/issues/302). I neither fully understand the meaning of `$&`(lastMatch) in regex replace groups nor have a idea how to resolve.

This article telling me [to not use the function in production environments](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastMatch), and indirectly to not use `JsRender` live.

Could anyone explain it to me and give a replacement of the line:

```
tmplFn(tmplOrMarkup.replace(rEscapeQuotes, "\\$&"), tmpl);
```

Regards

### Edit: Hopeless

Unfortunately JsRender and JDK leave the other holding the baby. JsRender says: $% works fine, JDK say never specified and not a bug.

Comment: You misunderstand the `$&`, it is not a *last match*, it is the whole match value. If your regex is `(\d+)_(\w+)`, replacing `1_a` with `($&)` will result in `(1_a)`. And `$&` is totally valid, the person who wrote the post was wrong.

Comment: `rEscapeQuotes` is equal to `/['"\\]/g`. This is also a valid regex. However, you might want to replace it with a more comprehensive `/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g`. Thus, try  `tmplFn(tmplOrMarkup.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, "\\$&"), tmpl);`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I wrote this bug-report because java has problems using $& (throwing `Illegal group reference`), see the stacktrace in the bug-report. You mean lastReplace is deprecated but not `$&`?

Comment: Using `/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g` java sais its not valid do you mean `/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|\[\]{}]/g`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Does not help.

Comment: Java? In Java you need to double backslashes, escape square brackets inside char classes and use `$0`. However, to escape a pattrtn in Java, you may just use `\Q` + pattern + `\E`. It is much easier than un JavaScript. Btw, where is your Java code in the question and why didn't you tag tbe question with Java tag?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew So i need two different scripts? One script for test of JSRender and the original script for live-website-productive-environment? But I like to use java for integration-testing.

Comment: Sorry, I do not think your question is clear to me. In short: 1) to escape the special characters in JS, the `.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, "\\$&")` is necessary, 2) in Java, you need to use `Pattern.quote(string)` (or enclose the pattern with `\Q` and `\E`). That is all I can help with here.

Comment: Also, `(pattern)` can be replaced with `$1` both in JS and Java.

Comment: I responded on the JsRender issue, here: https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender/issues/302#issuecomment-235981386

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not in fact a bug. The MDN article you link to is for the non-standard  `RegEx.lastMatch()` API, which is a programmatic way of accessing the last match. But JsRender is not using that API.

In fact JsRender is using `"$&"` as a replacement pattern in a replacement string, in the `someString.replace(regex, replacementstring)` call - which is standard usage in JavaScript RegEx scenarios.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace, where it says:

> The replacement string can include the following special replacement patterns: ... $& Inserts the matched substring.

The regex in that line of code is rEscapeQuotes, which is declared as   `rEscapeQuotes = /['"\\]/g` - and is a valid JavaScript regex.

That line is looking for `'` `"` or`\` and replacing them with the same character preceded by `\`.

Incidentally you should not be trying to run the same regex expressions used in JsRender as if they were Java regex expressions, since in Java the rules and validity of regex expressions can be quite different. JsRender of course runs in a JavaScript environment - the browser, or Node.js on the server...

Comment: Hi friend, the pattern `$&` leaks to a bug inside the jdk (you may notice the java-stacktrace in github). Sounds weird but in my case sun-java emulates a server and a complete a browser and inside the simulated browser java evaluate http, renders html,css and the javascript function `replace` using the java Regexp pendant **without the support** of `$&`. All this happens in the so-called intergration-tests of a webapplication.

Comment: Anyway, i have to drop jsrender because java has no support for $&. Thats why i asked for a replacement to be compatible to java.

Comment: So you are using a Java framework which emulates a browser and JavaScript execution, but has a bug in that it does not support the same regex APIs as JavaScript within its JavaScript emulation. Of course JsRender has to follow standard regex for JavaScript, not for Java - so cannot protect against this Java platform issue....

Comment: I understand that Java is the problem and I already opened a JavaIssue for this because the clean solution is to correct Java. Meanwhile I am searching for a replacement of `$&` but noone had a answer yet.

Comment: The Java-Issue can be found here: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8162831